# Is there a mechanical system with potential $V(\theta) = a \cosh(\theta)$?

Tags: classical-mechanics

The potential of a pendulum reads
$$ V(\theta) = mgl(1-\cos(\theta)) \, .$$
Is there any similarly simple system with potential
$$ V(\theta) = a  \cosh(\theta) \, ,$$
where $a$ is some constant that characterizes the system?

Comment: You need some exponential behaviour for this. Some situation with a Yukawa potential perhaps?

Comment: Btw, does $\theta$ have to be a real space parameter thing? Or could it be in momentum space?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Thanks! I was hoping for a real space potential.

Comment: The force is $a\sinh(\theta)$ so mechanical is rotational spring with this force characteristic